# How to iterate Map<Id, List<String>> in soql query to avoid governor limit hitting

Tags: apex, soql

I am having the `Map<Id, List<String>>` conModelcodeMap;

Need to iterate the `List<String>` inside soql query to get the result `Map<Id, List<id>>`

```
for(Applicable_Model__c appModelCode : [Select Id, Knowledge__c, Product__c, Product__r.Model_Code__c From Applicable_Model__c
                                            Where Product__r.Model_Code__c IN: conModelcodeMap.values() And Knowledge__r.PublishStatus = 'Online']){
        
    }
```

I am getting the below error:
Invalid bind expression type of List for column of type String

When i try to iterate conModelcodeMap values in the above soql query. and needs to frame a result like `Map<Id, List<id>> contDownloadsIdList=new Map<Id, List<id>>();`

Comment: conModelcodeMap would be a `list of list`. You need to iterate it and flatten the array first then you can bind it.

Comment: can you help me to show an example.

Comment: Based on the update you can take a list/set of I'd & use in the same way.

Comment: The map conModelCode has the contact id <Id> and its related list of codes

Comment: for each contact has list of model codes , i needs to iterate the list of model codes in the Applicable_Model__c object and get the list of knowledge__c id .
get the Map of contact id with the related knowledge ids

Comment: Can you post the actual snippet from the code. It would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

conModelcodeMap.values() would actually be a `list of list`. And you can not bind a list of list in the SOQL. You would need to flatten it to an list first then you can bind it & get the list of records.

```
SObject [] allRecords = new SObject []{};
for(SObject[] records: conModelcodeMap.values())
   allRecords.addAll(records);

for(Applicable_Model__c appModelCode : [Select Id, Knowledge__c, Product__c, Product__r.Model_Code__c From Applicable_Model__c
                                            Where Product__r.Model_Code__c IN: allRecords AND Knowledge__r.PublishStatus = 'Online']){
        
    }
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Sachin's answer.

Looking at the code here, do remember that one benefit of Apex is that the compiler is aware of SOQL syntax. That means you can add line breaks to make your code easier to read:

```
for (Applicable_Model__c model : [
    select Id, Knowledge__c, Product__c, Product__r.Model_Code__c
    from Applicable_Model__c
    where Product__r.Model_Code__c in :codes
    and Knowledge__r.PublishStatus = 'Online'
]) {
    // Do stuff     
}
```

without a mess of string concatenation. And this format helps get more done in the database (which is usually more effective than in Apex) because adding extra terms e.g. `order by` or `with security_enforced` is quite natural given it is a term per line and the additions are not way out to the right offscreen.